# Uwp.Ui.Lottie does not show animation

Tags: c#, uwp, lottie

I am using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Lottie in a UWP project. Simply, no animation file from [lottiefiles](https://lottiefiles.com/) works in this code.

```
<muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer x:Name="LottiePlayer" AutoPlay="True" Stretch="Uniform" Width="1280" Height="720" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
     <lottie:LottieVisualSource x:Name="LottieJsonSource" UriSource="ms-appx:///AnimatedVisuals/88759-exploding-star.json" Options="All"/>
</muxc:AnimatedVisualPlayer>
```

I also tried calling `PlayAsync(double, double, bool)` from code behind, but nothing happens. I Also tried different versions of Lottie, different SDK targets, but again, nothing happens.

I would not like to use classes from LottieGen, because the animations becomes slightly different.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uwp.Ui.Lottie does not show animation

During my testing. it could render animation with json file by using `LottieVisualSource`, but the json file should be set build action as content, please find your json file and right click properties-> build action -> set as content like the following. For making sure `AnimatedVisualPlayer` has right size, please set fix height and width for testing.

[image]